# How to change directory from the Win-R Window?

Tags: python, windows, command-line, command-prompt

After weeks of reading and experimenting, I still cannot figure out how to run Python3 programs, using batch files, from the WIN-R Run Window on Windows 10, if the batch files are saved in a different directory than the home directory.

It seems to work fine if I save both the .py file and the .bat file to the "C:\Users\Name" directory.  But I would like to save my programs to Dropbox so they can be used from different PCs.

My first issue was caused by a space in the Dropbox file path.  I learned that putting quotation marks around the path addresses this issue.

But I still cannot figure out how to run batch files from anywhere other than my home directory from the WIN-R Window.  Is it possible to run batch files from a Dropbox folder using the WIN-R Run Window?  Is it possible to change the directory in WIN-R?  I've tried creating a new shortcut as suggested by others here so that WIN-R opens in my Dropbox directory, but nothing I've done to date has worked.

Answer (score 0):

To change the directory from the Win-R Window, you can refer to this link:

http://www.sthda.com/english/wiki/running-rstudio-and-setting-up-your-working-directory-easy-r-programming

Hope this helps!